# Flutter : Unable to show Images from some urls

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-image

I am trying to display images in my flutter app. If I use a google link of the image, it is displayed. But, if I use my server URL, the image is not visible in the installed app.

I tried accessing the URL from both mobile and web browsers and it loads successfully there.

I have already used:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="...">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <!-- Add this -->
</manifast>
```

Comment: the image showed in dev mode ?

Comment: add this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: are you getting any error.?

Comment: Yes  Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: I have also added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" and uses-permission tags also